# Read and write using std::hexfloat

Tags: c++, floating-point, iostream, iomanip

This piece of code printed `0` on my machine, but I expected `0.3`. What's wrong? I'm using g++ 6.3.1 on latest Arch Linux. Compilation flags seem unrelevent.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main() {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << std::hexfloat << 0.3 << std::endl;
    double d = -1.0;
    while(s >> std::hexfloat >> d)
        std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `double d = std::strtod(s.str().c_str(), NULL);` as a workaround. It seems like a bug.

Comment: Running the code provided, I get `0.3` as the output. So seems like a bug to me too.

Comment: This is a bug, but not in gcc: see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81122#c1 .